# String search with regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Below is the code to search for text between the two tags `<title>` and `</title>`

```
url = "https://www.ilsole24ore.com/rss/italia--attualita.xml"
r = requests.get(url)
testo = r.text
pattern = "<title>(.*?)</title>"
result = re.findall(pattern, testo)
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

And so far everything is ok.

Now I want to find all the text (and also internal tags) between the two external tags `<item>` and `</item>`, changing the search pattern to:

```
pattern = "<item>(.*?)</item>"
```

But it doesn't find any match.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `<item>` tags are usually multi-lined and so your pattern never finds the closing `</item>`.

You might want to add the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag (or `(?s)` at the start of your pattern) to include the new-lines as part of the pattern. So you can choose between:

1. `pattern = "(?s)<item>(.*?)</item>"`
2. ```
   pattern = "<item>(.*?)</item>"
   result = re.findall(pattern, testo, re.DOTALL)
   ```